# hasClass() is not a function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT**

I had character blindness with this one and it was missing a dollar. Despite looking at the code in detail and running it through a number of online lint programs I didn't pick up on the missing dollar.

It was just one of those things and I'm sorry.

**/EDIT**

I've looked on stack overflow and the similar problems I've found appear to be when calling against an array, but I'm calling against an Id.

When I run the following I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: "#consoleLog".hasClass is not a function
```

code:

```
if(msg.data.match(/^LCERROR/) || msg.data.match(/^ERROR/)) {
  if (!('#consoleLog').hasClass('stop')){
     setInterval(function() {
       $('#consoleLog').animate( { backgroundColor : "#aa0000" }, 1000)
       .animate( { backgroundColor : "black" }, 1000);
      }, 100);
   };
 };
```

With my limited understanding of Jquery and Javascript I thought an Id was a valid DOM to call hasClass() with. It even has examples of it here: https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Any idea what might be happening here?

Purpose of the code is:
If the socket message contains ERROR or LCERROR, flash this div between black and red unless the stop class has been called.

Comment: `$('#consoleLog').hasClass` You missed out the dollar symbol

Comment: Dollar sign is missing on selector

Comment: instead of !('#consoleLog') use $('#consoleLog').

Comment: Thanks everyone. Bit of character blindness for some reason. i ran it through lint programs and everything and still didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed off the jQuery constructor function literal (`$`) in your `if()` statement:

```
if( msg.data.match(/^LCERROR/) || msg.data.match(/^ERROR/) ) 
{
    if( ! $('#consoleLog').hasClass('stop') )
    {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#consoleLog').animate( { backgroundColor : "#aa0000" }, 1000).animate( { backgroundColor : "black" }, 1000);
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are checking ``if( ! $('#consoleLog').hasClass('stop') ) {`` twice, in the first if block and the second in inner if statement, the first one is enough?

Comment: @hamism Sorry, first line was legacy from a previous edit. Updated.

Comment: Thanks. I win muppet of the week for not spotting that one.